# How to download old versions of macOS Monterey for Apple Silicon?

Tags: macos

We are currenty at macOS Monterey 12.3.

I need to simulate upgrades from older versions of macOS Monterey to 12.3 for which I plan to use Parallels.

Where can I download them?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Stumbled upon https://mrmacintosh.com/macos-12-monterey-full-installer-database-download-directly-from-apple/ and was able to download macOS Monterey 12.2.1 directly from Apple.

Comment: sunknudsen: You may want to post your own answer at [the duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos). Beware, some of the methods given in [your linked article](https://mrmacintosh.com/macos-12-monterey-full-installer-database-download-directly-from-apple/) (and links given in the article) have already been included in the existing answers.